# how to make a function that create a variable?

Tags: function, struct, types, julia

I want to make a function that create a new variable, my goal is:

```
   struct Test

  setArg(varName,Float64,10.1,1.2)

   end
```

That should return a struct `Test` with one argument `varName` from the Type `Float64` with max `10.1` and min `1.2`.
My problem is to know how to make the that function return a variable.

Or I'm thinking in another approach like this:

```
struct Test

      varName::setArg(Float64,10.1,1.2)

  end
```

here the function should just define a Type and max and min for the argument and that is okay, but I will prefer the first one if it is possible to do it in Julia.

So the question is how should my function/Type `setArg` look like?

Comment: It's difficult to understand your question, since you are using very unusual terminology. For example: functions don't create variables, they create values; structs don't have 'arguments', they have 'fields' or 'properties'. Generally, functions should never try to define types, types should be defined explicitly in code, or by macros. I don't mean to be nitpicky, it's just really hard to understand what you are asking. It would be easier if you create some example code, and then tell us _exactly_ what the output of that code should be, not just saying approximately what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You could create an incomplete mutable struct:

```
struct MyTest{T} #to allow different types while maintaining performance
  min::T
  max::T
  val::T
  valueset::Bool #to check if the struct is initialized
  sym::Symbol #to access
end
```

to allow the user to access the value with the identifier provided, we overload `Base.getproperty` for the `MyTest` struct:

```
function Base.getproperty(val::MyStruct, sym::Symbol) 
#identifier matches and the value was set
  if val.sym==sym &  val.valueset
    return val.val
  else
    throw(error("oops") 
  end
end
```

finally, we make the struct with setArg:

```
function setArg(sym, type, min, max) 
  min = convert(type, min) 
  max = convert(type, max) 
  dummyval = zero(type) #
  return MyTest(min, max, dummyval, false, sym) 
end
```

finally, we make a function that sets the value, by calling the struct:

```
function (val::MyTest)(value) #a functor
  if val.min <= value <= val.max
    val.val = value
    val.valueset = true
  else
    throw(error("out of bounds")) 
  end
  return val
end
```

I imagine that the usecase is something like this :

```
constructor = setArg(:myname, Float64, 0.2, 0.5)
val1 = constructor(0.4)
val2 = constructor(0.5) 
val3 = constructor(0.6) #error
val2.myname == 0.5
```

Comment: I didn't understand the question, but if this is what they meant, it's pretty cool (independent of whether it's a good or bad idea - which depends on context).

Comment: Hahahah, I didn't understood it either, and I don't recommend using this, but it showcases two good features: overloading `Base.setproperty` and functors